# Referencing a Java list from a Servlet in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, servlets, intellij-idea

I have a list which is pulled from a Postgres database and I need to be able to reference/manipulate it with JavaScript.

**I have updated the code as shown below:**

Here is the Servlet's doGet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse json) 
throws ServletException, IOException {

List<Employee> employees = uds.findAll();
req.setAttribute("employees", employees);
json.setContentType("application/json");
json.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(employees));


}
```

And here is what I currently have in JavaScript:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/project1attempt/servlet", true);

// send request
ajax.send();

// event to get response
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Case state is 4 e o http.status for 200, your request is OK.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var data = ajax.responseText;
        // the return
        console.log(data);
    }
}
}
```

The issue I am having at this point is that the client is not receiving data in JSON format. If I log the data as shown above, the log will produce something along the lines of the following:

```
[Employee{, employee_id='123456', email='lt@gmail.com', firstName='Juan', 
lastName='Terri'}, Employee{, employee_id='2', email='sstark@mail.com', 
firstName='Sansa', lastName='Stark'}]
```

This is the correct data, but not in a useful format.

However, if I try to do `console.log(JSON.parse(data))`, then I receive `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 1`.

I believe this is a simple syntax error on my part in the servlet, but am unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: You'll have to use something like JSP, something on the server; the Java object does not get sent to the client.

Comment: if this is a new project, is there any reason you are not taking advantage of the magic in Spring Boot?

Comment: I'm not using  Spring Boot because I am in a training program and we have not yet reached Spring Boot, therefore we're advised to stay from it for this project.

Comment: I switched over to JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other noobs like me, I've compiled the following complete solution for this issue:

The Servlet should look something like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
ServletException, IOException {

resp.setContentType("application/json");
List<Employee> employees = uds.findAll();
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(employees);
resp.getWriter().write(json);
```

`uds.findAll()` is a method which returns a list of objects. ObjectMapper is a Jackson utility (Gson is another option, I believe). This puts the list into JSON format.

The HTML or JSP should look like this:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/project1attempt/servlet", true);

// send request
ajax.send();

// event to get response
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Case state is 4 e o http.status for 200, your request is OK.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var data = ajax.responseText;
        // the return
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    }
}
```

This will get the list of objects in a usable format which you can then manipulate with JavaScript to do whatever you'd like. Hopefully this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

You should use request.getAttribute():

```
<%
  List<Employee> theEmployees = request.getAttribute("employees");
%>
```

But if you want to effectively use it in your javascript , it is recommended to convert it to json .

Comment: Usage of scriptlets is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your servlet response to json and get your data with Ajax 
This is a sample to do it!

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajax.open("GET", "your_url_here", true);

// send request
ajax.send();

// event to get response
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
  // Case state is 4 e o http.status for 200, your request is OK.
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var data = ajax.responseText;
         // the return
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informed response! I implemented your suggestion and got it partially working. I updated the original post with the current issue.

Comment: Try to change your response. Add Gson and use with this sample-> Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(dataResponse);